# C - Forking from a single parent

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child

I'm trying to write a small program that forks processes from a single parent. Currently my code does this a few times but then the children create more child processes, which I want to eliminate.

```
int main() {
    pid_t c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        c = fork(); 

        if(c < 0) { 
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if( c > 0 ) { 
            printf("parentID = %d, childID = %d\n", getppid(i), getpid(i)); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to modify it so that fork is only forking from the parent though.

EDIT: thanks for the help, got the solution:

```
int main() {
    pid_t c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        c = fork(); 

        if(c < 0) { 
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if( c > 0 ) { 
            printf("parentID = %d, childID = %d\n", getppid(i), getpid(i)); 
        }

        else {
            exit(0); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) what is the variable 'n' supposed to be?  it is not defined.  Suggest using the value in the 'pid_t' variable.   2) The question is about a runtime problem, but the posted code does not compile. Please post the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing in the posted code is recognizing the child (0 == pid)

so a child hits (and skips) the two 'if' statements.

hits the end of the loop,

branches back to the top of the loop, calls fork()....etc.

Suggest: adding

```
elseif( 0 == pid ) 
{ // then child ...   
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The child process does not enter any part of the `if` block, and just loops back to the top of the `for` loop creating more children.  Also, the `if (n > 0)` block gets run for the parent, not the child, since `fork` returns 0 to the parent and the child's pid to the parent.

Change `if (n > 0)` to if `(n == 0)`, and call `exit()` at the bottom of the block to prevent the child from continuing.  Also, `getpid()` and `getppid()` don't take any arguments.

```
int main() {
    pid_t c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        c = fork(); 

        if(c < 0) { 
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if( c == 0 ) { 
            printf("parentID = %d, childID = %d\n", getppid(), getpid()); 
            exit(0);    // <-- here
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: none of the OPs code does anything with the child (0 == pid) none of this answer does anything with the child.    The variable 'n' is not defined in this answer

Comment: the n problem was my mistake, I accidently wrote n instead of c originally and editted it now after realising.

Comment: @user3324536 Your solution won't print the pids you expect.  The `printf` should be in the child's block, and `getpid` and `getppid` don't take any parameters.